# App terminating only change made has been to bundle identifiers

Tags: ios

I have an working app. Recently I changed the bundle identifier. It builds but then when using it, it terminates.

My dev is not responding to me so I'm a bit stuck.

I am getting the following:

```
2018-01-21 09:49:56.258810+0000 team[14965:850466] Base URL: https://ads.tapdaq.com  
2018-01-21 09:49:56.259807+0000 team[14965:850466] [INFO] [Tapdaq] Tapdaq SDK is set to LIVE MODE  
2018-01-21 09:49:56.327955+0000 team[14965:850466]  set Document Path  
2018-01-21 09:49:56.328866+0000 team[14965:850466] Save data in Document Directory  
2018-01-21 09:49:56.343569+0000 team[14965:850466] Success for write GIF in Document Directory  
2018-01-21 09:49:56.343660+0000 team[14965:850466] 1111111  
2018-01-21 09:49:56.345472+0000 team[14965:850466] Screen: Home Screen  
2018-01-21 09:49:56.552085+0000 team[14965:850466] [INFO] [TDLaunchService] Tapdaq launched. SDK Version: ios-sdk_1.2.0  
2018-01-21 09:49:56.554165+0000 team[14965:850466] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/sutcliffestu/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E01F9D4F-EB0B-49D1-B053-9116932B5A4F/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles  
2018-01-21 09:49:56.554524+0000 team[14965:850466] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.  
2018-01-21 09:49:56.556447+0000 team[14965:850466] [INFO] [TDLaunchURLRequest] About to send launch request  
2018-01-21 09:49:56.894782+0000 team[14965:850466] Could not successfully update network info during initialization.  
2018-01-21 09:50:03.788714+0000 team[14965:850466] Screen: Emoji Screen  
2018-01-21 09:50:04.982605+0000 team[14965:850466] WARNING: GoogleAnalytics 3.15 void GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *) (GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler.m:48): Uncaught exception: *** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter  
2018-01-21 09:50:05.014942+0000 team[14965:850466] invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' provided to CFRunLoopRunSpecific - break on _CFRunLoopError_RunCalledWithInvalidMode to debug. This message will only appear once per execution.  
2018-01-21 09:50:09.989023+0000 team[14965:850466] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'  

*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d51412b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010cba8f41 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d589245 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000108ce8566 -[NSURL(NSURL) initFileURLWithPath:] + 127
    4   Foundation                          0x0000000108ce84d4 +[NSURL(NSURL) fileURLWithPath:] + 45
    5   team                                0x000000010868ca5e -[EmojiViewController onShare:] + 622
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000109a9c972 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000109c1bc3c -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000109c1bf59 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000109c1ae86 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 618
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000109b12807 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2807
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000109b13f2a -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4124
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000109ab7365 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000128cf649d -[UIApplicationAccessibility sendEvent:] + 85
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010a403a1d __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2809
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010a406672 __handleEventQueueInternal + 5957
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d4b7101 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d556f71 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 81
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d49ba19 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 185
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d49afff __CFRunLoopRun + 1279
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d49a889 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010ed049c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000109a9b5d6 UIApplicationMain + 159
    23  team                                0x000000010868c10f main + 111
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010f406d81 start + 1
    25  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

When I build the app without changing the bundle identifier it runs perfectly:

```
2018-01-21 10:54:08.016323+0000 Doodlemoji Plus[16688:959772] Base URL: https://ads.tapdaq.com
2018-01-21 10:54:08.016919+0000 Doodlemoji Plus[16688:959772] [INFO] [Tapdaq] Tapdaq SDK is set to LIVE MODE
2018-01-21 10:54:08.073345+0000 Doodlemoji Plus[16688:959772] 1111111
2018-01-21 10:54:08.075258+0000 Doodlemoji Plus[16688:959772] Screen: Home Screen
2018-01-21 10:54:08.283539+0000 Doodlemoji Plus[16688:959772] [INFO] [TDLaunchService] Tapdaq launched. SDK Version: ios-sdk_1.2.0
2018-01-21 10:54:08.285879+0000 Doodlemoji Plus[16688:959772] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/sutcliffestu/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/88C33547-8197-4E13-B087-BE73D07E1720/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2018-01-21 10:54:08.286262+0000 Doodlemoji Plus[16688:959772] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
2018-01-21 10:54:08.302926+0000 Doodlemoji Plus[16688:959772] [INFO] [TDLaunchURLRequest] About to send launch request
2018-01-21 10:54:10.803445+0000 Doodlemoji Plus[16688:959772] Screen: Emoji Screen
2018-01-21 10:54:16.976363+0000 Doodlemoji Plus[16688:959772] [core] SLComposeViewController extensionIdentifierForActivityType: com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToTwitter => com.apple.share.Twitter.post
2018-01-21 10:54:16.976526+0000 Doodlemoji Plus[16688:959772] [core] SLComposeViewController extensionIdentifierForActivityType: com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToFacebook => com.apple.share.Facebook.post
2018-01-21 10:54:16.976645+0000 Doodlemoji Plus[16688:959772] [core] SLComposeViewController extensionIdentifierForActivityType: com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToWeibo => com.apple.share.SinaWeibo.post
2018-01-21 10:54:16.976786+0000 Doodlemoji Plus[16688:959772] [core] SLComposeViewController extensionIdentifierForActivityType: com.apple.UIKit.activity.TencentWeibo => com.apple.share.TencentWeibo.post
2018-01-21 10:54:16.976908+0000 Doodlemoji Plus[16688:959772] [core] SLComposeViewController extensionIdentifierForActivityType: com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToFlickr => com.apple.share.Flickr.post
2018-01-21 10:54:16.977013+0000 Doodlemoji Plus[16688:959772] [core] SLComposeViewController extensionIdentifierForActivityType: com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToVimeo => com.apple.share.Vimeo.post
2018-01-21 10:54:16.980529+0000 Doodlemoji Plus[16688:959772] [core] SLComposeViewController initWithExtension:  {id = com.apple.mobileslideshow.StreamShareService} requestedServiceType: (null)
2018-01-21 10:54:16.981132+0000 Doodlemoji Plus[16688:959772] [core] SLComposeViewController addExtensionItem:  - userInfo: {
    NSExtensionItemAttachmentsKey =     (
        " {types = (\n    \"com.compuserve.gif\",\n    \"public.file-url\"\n)}"
    );
```

I'm sure I'm missing something glaringly obvious but any of you seasoned guys could spot what I cannot I would be really appreciative.

Comment: Did u created provisioning profiles for your new bundle identifier in your developer account?

Comment: What do you do in the `onShare` function of `EmojiViewController`? It seems you are passing a nil string to the file URL constructor.

Comment: Update your question with your `EmojiViewController onShare:` method.

Answer (score 0):

As Im understanding your crash report, your projecct have google service plist which is using your bundle identifier.

So when you first registered into  google console you have given old bundle identifier(says `xxx`) which makes it work perfectly but when you update your project identifier (says `yyy`) project identifier of google service does not match with the project identifier.

So if these scenario is true in your project then change the google service plist with the new google service with new project identifier.

Please check this. Hop it helps. If still having issue then let me know.